# Get data with JavaScrip after page load ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing TamperMonkey UserScript and need to get data from the website, but those data loaded with ajax after the page loads. Basically, I do search in an input which gives me data without reloading the page (I think works with ajax).
I wrote this, but the "timestamp" doesnt exist till I don't search for something.

```
var bookTime = document.getElementsByClassName("timestamp")[0];
```

Comment: Stick it in a `$(document).ready(function(){})`. That will wait for the page to load before doing anything

Answer (score 0):

I added a "save" button to the page.
Put the "var bookTime..." in the onclick function and works fine :)

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Try to write a complete and good answer by providing a code example to show how it should be done.